# How to hide a div after a given length of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If a user hasn't clicked on or hovered over a DIV for more than 30 seconds, I want to disable or hide it using JavaScript, but I haven't been able to find any code for this scenario. Please help me to do this.

For example:

```
<div id="check">

    Sample codes

</div>
```

Comment: "_ideal time calculation of a DIV_". What do you mean? You want the DIV to be hidden for 30 seconds, and to appear after that?

Comment: @blex User not click or hover the div content more than 30 seconds, the div content should be hide

Comment: to get your question clear... you want to hide the div after 30 seconds, if the user dont click or hover it ?

Comment: @Dwza Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use mouseover and mouseout.

There are many solutions I think using a timeout is simplest.

```
var hoverTimer;

function beginTimer()
{
    hoverTimer = setTimeout(timeUp, 30000); //30 Second Timeout
}

function timeUp()
{
    alert("Time Up");
}

function killTimer()
{  
    clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="check" onmouseover="beginTimer();" onmouseout="killTimer();">

Sample codes

</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly right your answer. Might be my question is not clear to understand. But I found the answer by using your answer as hint. Thanks 1vote

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var intervalID = setInterval(myFunction, 30000);

function myFunction(){
    //logic goes here
    $('#check').hide();
};

$("#check").hover( function () {
    window.clearInterval(intervalID)
    },
    function () {
        intervalID = setInterval(myFunction, 30000);
});
```